# QGIS - Creating a polygon from a section of a different line

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I would like to create a polygon layer using a section of a different line layer. I selected the line component (orange highlight) which came from a high tide line shapefile and would like to use that line plus the others to make a polygon of the whole area (I georeferenced a snip of the required area to give me the boundary).

It looks like a polygon but acts like a line. Using the line to polygon tool results in the second attachment - I would like the coastal component (southern section) to be included in the whole polygon. I could draw round the entire coast but that would take quite some time..

Is anyone able to provide some assistance?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the area you would like to add:

[image]

You could convert the coastal lines and create polygons. From there, use the algorithm difference between the polygon in brown and the coastal line polygons. You could then copy the polygon you want to the brown polygon layer then merge them manually with the merge tool. Here is an example:

[image]

**Answer Edit/Update:
==================**

1. I have downloaded the coastlines and added them as a line layer.

[image]

2. Added your orange color lines.
3. Clipped the coastlines to extents

[image]

4. Added new lines to connect the islands with the main island

[image]

5. Copied the lines from the coastlines to the digitized lines

[image]

6. Removed the lines I do not need (using the split tool then delete feature) to avoid unwanted results

[image]

7. Run the "Polygonize" algorithm and here is the result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, that's not the area I'm after sorry. I want the thin orange boundary in the first image - I took the highlighted coastal area from another layer then added the rest of it myself. My problem is that the line-to-polygon tool connects the ends of the section I drew, resulting in the straight line across the bottom as seen in the brown polygon. The top of the south island is included in the polygon (the Kahurangi National Park) when it shouldn't be and the bay to the east, above Nelson, should be included. Hope that's clearer. Cheers

Comment: Lane, the issue that you may be having is that the coastlines for the island are not connected. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I had added in those bridging lines but they mustn't have snapped to the coastline. I traced around the coasts manually and it ended up working. Thanks for your help once again.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to enable snapping to the orange line and other relevant layer only, enable tracing in the snapping toolbar, and then digitise the polygon by snapping to vertices around the line.

You won't need to manually trace the whole coastal section; if you snap to one vertex on the east side and then to another vertex on the west, the digitising line should automatically follow all the vertices in between.